# Google Sheets Script: Get A1Notation For Each Cell In Named Range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The function I'm working on does an optimisation of the force required by a rudder foil (stabilator) on an America's Cup AC75 yacht, to balance the longitudinal moments of the sail forces. This is done by altering the angle of the stabilator, from initially providing an upward (positive) force, then as sail forces increase, the stabilator has to create a downward (negative) force.

The stabilator angles are in a column, and when it is changed, other calculations work out if it balances the sail forces. If it doesn't, there is a "Delta" column that indicates a value whether the rudder foil needs to provide more/less force, via it's angle.

I tried using Named Ranges for the column of Angles, and another for Delta. The code should iterate through adding a bit more (or less) angle to the stabilator, and each time, check the Delta.  My code is wrong.

What I need to do is get the Angle value of one Angle cell, incrementally increase/decrease it, then setValue of that cell. Next is to getValue of the corresponding Delta cell, to see if I'm at Zero (plus/minus a small amount). If not, via a while loop, I increase/decrease the Angle again, setValue, recheck the Delta, and so on.

My problem is that I do not know how to get the A1Notation of each cell in the Named Ranges as I iterate through it, so that I can repeatedly getValue and setValue for just the single cell at a time?

```
function c_Optimise_Stabilator() {
// Author: Max Hugen
// Date: 20102-12-07
// Purpose: Attempt to optimise Stab Angle to balance with Stab Target Force

/* WARNING: This function may eventually cause a circular reference, so ensure there is an "escape".
 *          May occur if other optimisation functions are also run?
 * OPTIMISATION: Try in this order:
 *          1. Optimise Transverse Moments 
 *          2. Optimise Stabilator 
 *          3. Check, and if necessary, rerun Optimise Transverse Moments 
 *          4. Check, and if necessary, rerun Optimise Stabilator
 *             If Optimise Stabilator returns all Angles OK, we're good!
*/

  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

//  var target_sheet = "Analysis";
//  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Analysis");
  var msg = ""; // gather input for Logger
  var s = "";   // short info for testing alerts, then added to msg
  var log = true; // whether to output msg to the Logger

  // angle range
  const maxAngle = 2.0, minAngle = -0.2, incAngle = 0.1;
  //limits
  var maxLoopIterations=10;  // to avoid excessive iterations
  var minDelta=0.02;          // to limit the minimum size of Delta tested
  // counters
  var i=0, loopIterations=0;
  // Original and New Vals
  var originalAngle=0.0, newAngle=0.0, originalDelta=0.0, newDelta=0.0;

  // ranges used in getRange - variable here, for testing. <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
/* 
  var sAngle = "Optimise_Stab_Angle";
  var sDelta = "Optimise_Stab_Delta";
 
  var sAngle = "Analysis!AF14:AG14";   // 1 rows (but only 2 cols now) - failing
  var sDelta = "Analysis!AM14:AM14";
*/  
  var sAngle = "Analysis!AF10:AG13";   // 4 rows
  var sDelta = "Analysis!AM10:AM13";

  var rAngle = ss.getRange(sAngle);
  var dAngle = rAngle.getValues();
  var rDelta = ss.getRange(sDelta);
  var dDelta = rDelta.getValues();
  
  originalAngle = Math.round(dAngle[i][1]*1000)/1000;
  originalDelta = Math.round(dDelta[i][0]*1000)/1000;

  var iLen = rAngle.getNumRows();

  for(i=0; i<iLen; i++){
    s = "";

    newAngle = originalAngle;
    s += "    Vb: " + dAngle[i][0] + "; Original Angle: " + originalAngle + "; originalDelta: " + originalDelta + "\r\n";

    // if stabilator force is below target (negative Delta), increase stab angle unless at maxAngle.
    if ( Math.abs(Math.round(dDelta[i][0]*100)/100) > minDelta && originalAngle < maxAngle) {

      loopIterations = 1; 
      while (newAngle <= maxAngle) {
        try {
          if ( newAngle == maxAngle ) {
            s += "                 MAX.ANGLE: newDelta" + newDelta + "; originalDelta: " + originalDelta;
            break;
          }
          // Have to update the Delta range, to check if Delta still too high/low
          var rDelta = ss.getRange(sDelta);
          var dDelta = rDelta.getValues();
          newDelta = Math.round(dDelta[i][0]*1000)/1000;
          
          if ( Math.abs(Math.round(newDelta*100)/100) < minDelta ) {
            s += "                 COMPLETED: newDelta" + newDelta + "; originalDelta: " + originalDelta;
            break;
          }
          if ( loopIterations > maxLoopIterations ) {
            s += "                 EXCEEDED maxLoopIterations of " + maxLoopIterations;
            break;
          }
        } catch(err) {
          Logger.log (c_ErrorToString (err) + "\n" + "Vb: " + dAngle[i][0]);
        }
        newAngle += incAngle;  // for some reason, this may STILL produce a number like 1.400000003 (example only)
        newAngle = Math.round(newAngle*1000)/1000;
        
        // set the new angle
        dAngle[i][1] = newAngle;
        // update the iteration count
        loopIterations ++
      } 
    }
    
    // if stabilator force is above target (positive Delta), decrease stab angle unless at minAngle.
    else if ( Math.abs(Math.round(dDelta[i][0]*100)/100) > minDelta && originalAngle > minAngle) {
      loopIterations = 1; 
      
      while (newAngle >= minAngle) {

        try {
          if ( newAngle == minAngle ) {
            s += "                 MIN.ANGLE: newDelta" + newDelta + "; originalDelta: " + originalDelta;
            break;
          }
          // Have to update the Delta range, to check if Delta still too high/low
          var rDelta = ss.getRange(sDelta);
          var dDelta = rDelta.getValues();
          newDelta = Math.round(dDelta[i][0]*1000)/1000;
          
          if ( Math.abs(Math.round(newDelta*100)/100) < minDelta ) {
            s += "                 COMPLETED: newDelta" + newDelta + "; originalDelta: " + originalDelta;
            break;
          }
          if ( loopIterations > maxLoopIterations ) {
            s += "                 EXCEEDED maxLoopIterations of " + maxLoopIterations;
            break;
          }
        } catch(err) {
          Logger.log (c_ErrorToString (err) + "\n" + "Vb: " + dAngle[i][0]);
        }

        newAngle -= incAngle;  // for some reason, this may STILL produce a number like 1.400000003 (example only)
        newAngle = Math.round(newAngle*1000)/1000;
        
        // set the new angle
        dAngle[i][1] = newAngle;
        // update the iteration count
        loopIterations ++
      } 
    }
    
    msg += s + "\r\n";
  }
  rAngle.setValues(dAngle);
  
  msg = "c_Optimise_Stabilator \r\n" + msg
  Logger.log(msg);
  ui.alert(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the way to get the cell A1Notation, use getCell() on the range, then getA1Notation.

```
cellA1 = range.getCell(1, 1).getA1Notation();
```